# Intellij IDEA toolbar usability

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, usability

The `Save` button on IntelliJ IDEA toolbar is never disabled (grayed out) even though there has everything been saved. This is actually misleading the programmer by incorrectly hinting that there is something to save all the time.

But, the `Redo` button (see image bellow), for example, is properly disabled when there is nothing to redo.
[image]

Am I missing anything, any of my configuration is wrong?

(This behaviour is tested on Mac and Ubuntu)

Comment: Can confirm this on Windows too (should be equal on all OS due to Java). As it says "Save all files and settings", this might be wanted behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration holds good and your observation too. It is never disabled. Some how the tabs also doesn't show up the modified files(By default).

The behavior of this is sometimes misleading but to show up the modification in the file,

`Settings --> Editor --> Editor Tabs --> Mark Modified tabs with asterik`

If this feature is enabled, we will come to know that the file is changed.

[image]

Comment: This is a good and close workaround (I voted +1) but not a solution to the problem.

Comment: Well, I do agree that how to disable the save button is the question, AFAIK, this is not possible in community edition and don't know about the licensed.